Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin
После подключения FireBase возникла следующая ошибка:

/User/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/09dda4ac7374eff59c2f1f5a2426d3b4/transformed/firebase-auth-23.0.0-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.firebase-auth-api_firebase-auth-api.kotlin_module:
Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary
version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

В соседних ветках пишут что надо поменять ext.kotlin_version в файле build.gradle, но у меня такого нет:
build.gradle(Project):
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.2' apply false
}

build.gradle(Module):
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.telegram'
    compileSdk 34
    viewBinding.enabled = true

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.telegram"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    implementation "com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:7.0.0"

    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2"
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.1"

    implementation "com.mikepenz:materialdrawer-nav:7.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:23.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}

Manifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Telegram"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.RegisterActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


У вас версия Котлин выставляется через плагин
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false

Используйте хотя бы любую версию 1.8 (последняя 1.8.22) и проблема с компиляцией должна уйти.
https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.android/1.8.22
Как альтернатива можете понизить версию firebase-auth, думаю 22.1.2 будет компилиться с Котлин 1.7

Подскажите, где меняется firebase-auth
я тупой..

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:23.0.0'

Благодарю. Всё работает
